# unity-photon- how can get other player's companent

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a multiplayer game. I want to make a system. When a "x" player play a game and there is a "y" player. "x" player should see "y" player's score on "y" player's head. It okay I made it. But I want when "x" player's score less then "y" player's, "y" player's nickname become red. In short how can get other player's score?

Answer (score 0):

An option can be an Game Manager System where all the info can be collected and manipulated. Here you can check if the score 1 is less than score 2. With bool you can check and uncheck the colors.

Hope this will help you to develop an idea of how to do it.

Comment: sorry i forgot to write but There will be at least 20 players it is the problem ı couldn't find a way to make it

Comment: How do you instantiate a new player? or do they have like an id?   You can make an array for every player. When a new player is on , add it to that array. Then be careful what info you add there.

Comment: Or another way is every new player has like an profile where you save his name, point , health. And again, a Manager System script will do the calculations. I hope to help you more but i need to see some insides, how it was made every player .

Comment: there are max 20 players on game.  a random player has just a score. like agario game.

Comment: I will take a look on how to add score on every player, then you can just SetActive the random one